# Как отобразить PDF файл на странице JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

Имеется БД, в которой лежат книги. Контент книги в базе записан в типе blob. Как можно отобразить контент средствами браузера? Перед тем как написать сюда гуглил, но в основном запросы не соответствуют моим требованиям (или плохо смотрел). Спасибо.
n/ **UPD**. Как советуют @Roman C и @Sckoriy написал простенький сервлет:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        int id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
        SearchController sc = (SearchController) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("searchController");

        byte[] pdf = sc.getPdf(id);

        response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
        out.write(pdf);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Объект `searchController` хранит в себе текущий список книг — объектов типа `book`. Метод `getPdf` возвращает массив байтов нужной книги (id), который я безуспешно пытаюсь отобразить в `<iframe src="/Reader?id=1"></iframe>` — получаю свой заслуженный `404`.

Comment: Пожалуй блоб нельзя разместить на странице jsf. Но если использовать iframe to можно туда загрузить PDF.

Comment: Ну смотри.Я ответ тебе пишу, с примером только на jsp(Скоро закончу).Суть такова : Берешь сервлет,закидаешь туда ссылку на Blob.Выводишь потоками через getWriter.Потом,на странице создаешь iframe и в url указываешь имя сервлета,который выводит Blob и все.

Comment: Либо же,можешь с БД прочитать Blob и записать его в файле ServletContext . А потом в iframe просто делаешь запрос на документ,который лежит на твоем веб-приложении(сервере)(Но это тупой вариант)

Comment: Ты уверен,что там нужен Слеш?Его не надо ставить.

Comment: Слэш нужен, но попробовал без него — результат тот же 404 not found.

Comment: Если not found то перепроверь Web.Xml и то,какой ты url вводишь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим,что есть бд с такой таблицей :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как один с вариантов,который позволяет вывести на страницу Blob вот :

1.Создаем html страницу

```
Куча тегов..//
<iframe src = "http://172.16.108.183:8080/PracticeV0/IFrame?id=4" 
height = "500" weight = "500"></iframe>
```

Тег iframe создает плавающий фрейм - то,что вам надо.Он будет делать запрос на сервлет,который будет записывать в исходящий поток файлы.(Но,об этом чуть позже)

2.Для того,чтобы убрать по максиму бизнес-логику от сервлета нужно создать класс Модель, в которой будут производится "вычисления".(Шаблон MVC)

```
public class ModelFiles {
private Connection connect;
private PreparedStatement prepare;
private Statement stat;
private ResultSet result;
private Blob blob;

public ModelFiles(Connection connect){
  this.connect = connect;
}
public Blob readPDF(int id) {
        try {
            stat = connect.createStatement();
            result = stat.executeQuery("Select PDF from files where id = " + id + ";");
            result.next();
            blob = result.getBlob("PDF");
            result.close();
        }catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        return blob;
}
```

Теперь перейдем к контроллеру - сервлету .
    package Controllers;

```
public class toIfraime extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Создаем модель и передаем ей подключение(У меня подключение
//хранится в атрибутах контекста приложения)Добавляю я его туда при запуске
//приложения - Слушателям сервлетов , привет!

ModelFiles model = new 
ModelFiles((Connection)getServletContext().getAttribute("Connection");
//Дальше,получаем Blob от модели
//В параметр передаем id файла
Blob blob = model.readPDF(3);
//Теперь можно и заголовки подготовить
response.setContentLength(blot.getSize());//эту строчку нужно поместить в try catch ибо метод getSize может выбросить исключение SQLException
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
//Теперь начинаем само чтение и записывание Blob

InputStream is = null;
BufferedInputStream buff = null;
OutputStream out = null;
BufferedOutputStream buffOut = null;
   try{
      is = blob.getBinaryStream();//Создаем простой входящий поток байтов.
      buff = new BufferedInputStream(is);//Создаeм буфферизированный входящий поток 
      //байтов
      out = response.getOutputStream();//Создаем просто исходящий поток байтов
      buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(out);//Буфферизируем исходящий поток
      int bit = 0 ; //будем читать байтами
          while((bit = buff.read()) != -1){//Пока не закончиться входящий 
          //поток,записывай байт в исходящий
            buffOut.write(bit);//В response записываем байт   
          }

   catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      if(buff != null){
          buff.close();
       }
      if(buffOut != null){
          buffOut.close();
   }
```

Вот web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>FrameFile</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Controllers.toIfraime</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FrameFile</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/LoadPDF</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

Вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Hа `setContentLength` выбрасывает `NullPointerException`. Буду копать.